# Text Manipulation using awk/sed

Tags: awk, sed

Can I insert text just after function name & opening braces

eg:

```
void func()
{
Some text needs to be inserted before me
}
```

o/p

```
void func()
{
Hello here I am...
Some text needs to be inserted before me
}
```

using awk/sed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed '/^void func()/!b;n;a\Hello here I am...' file
```

This bails out if it does not match on the `func` name. Having matched it prints that line, reads the next and appends the required string to it which will be printed following the `{`.

The same can be achieved using:

```
sed -e '/^void func()/{n;a\Hello here I am...' -e '}' file
```

Comment: thanks potong...it is working, but what does "!b" & "{n" means

Comment: @Soumyadutta: the command `/.../!b` means on not matching break, as no label is provided the default is bail out of any subsequent commands  for the current line and so read the next line and begin at the start of sed commands. The `{...}` construct just groups the commands enclosed to the address match i.e the `/^void func()/`. As the append command needs a newline to terminate it, the closing `}` needs to be in a separate `-e` command.

Answer (score 0):

sed is for simple substitutions on individual lines, for anything more interesting you should be using awk. For example, using GNU awk for multi-char RS, note how the script works regardless of these common function definition layout possibilities:

```
$ cat file                                                  
void func()
{
Some text needs to be inserted before me
}

void
func()
{
Some text needs to be inserted before me
}

void func() {
Some text needs to be inserted before me
}
```

.

```
$ awk -v RS='^$' -v ORS= '{gsub(/void\s+func\(\)\s*{/,"&\nHello here I am...")}1' file
void func()
{
Hello here I am...
Some text needs to be inserted before me
}

void
func()
{
Hello here I am...
Some text needs to be inserted before me
}

void func() {
Hello here I am...
Some text needs to be inserted before me
}
```